# Shopify Schema not passing color to class in stylesheet

Tags: css, shopify, liquid

This is my CSS

```
<style>
        /* Color of active silder dot */
    .slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
      color: {{ block.settings.colorDotActive }};
    }
</style>
```

This is my schema block

```
{
    "name": "Homepage",
    "blocks": [
         {
                  "type": "home_slider",
                  "name": "Home Page Slider",
                  "settings": [
                  {
                    "type": "text",
                    "id": "sliderSpeed",
                    "label": "Slider Speed",
                    "default": "300",
                    "info": "100 = 1 second"
                 },
                 {
                  "type": "color",
                  "id": "colorDotActive",
                  "label": "Active Dot Color"
                },
                {
                  "type": "color",
                  "id": "colorDot",
                  "label": "Dot Color"
                }
              ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For whatever reason the color is not changing, the color picker in Shopify is there though. It's just not passing it to the class.

I've also tried using {% stylesheet %} tags,  but that didn't work either.

---

Here is the entire file for those requesting -

```
{% for block in section.blocks %}
{% case block.type %}

{% when 'full_image_hero' %}
<div class="full_image_hero_container">
  {% if block.settings.image_hero_mobile != blank %}
    <a href="{{ block.settings.hero_link }}" class="hide_on_desktop">
      <img src="{{ block.settings.image_hero_mobile | img_url: 'large' }}" />
    </a>
  {% else %}
  <a href="{{ block.settings.hero_link }}" class="hide_on_desktop">
    <img src="{{ block.settings.image_hero | img_url: 'large' }}" />
  </a>
  {% endif %}
  
  {% if block.settings.image_hero != blank %}
    <a href="{{ block.settings.hero_link }}" class="hide_on_mobile">
      <img src="{{ block.settings.image_hero | img_url: 'master' }}" />
    </a>
  {% endif %}
</div><!-- end .full_image_hero_container -->

{% when 'hero_image_and_text' %}
<div class="hero_image_and_text_container
            {% if block.settings.mobile_image_full_width %}
            full_width
            {% endif %}
            "
     style="background-color:{{ block.settings.hero_background_color }};">
  <div class="hero_text float_{{ block.settings.hero_layout_format }} hide_on_mobile">
    {% if block.settings.hero_subtitle != blank %}
    <h3>{{ block.settings.hero_subtitle }}</h3>
    {% endif %}
    {% if block.settings.hero_title != blank %}
    <h2>{{ block.settings.hero_title }}</h2>
    {% endif %}
    {% if block.settings.hero_text != blank %}
    <p>{{ block.settings.hero_text }}</p>
    {% endif %}
    <a href="{{ block.settings.hero_link }}">
      <button class="button">{{ block.settings.hero_button_text }}</button>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="hero_image">
    {% if block.settings.image_hero_mobile != blank %}
    <a href="{{ block.settings.hero_link }}" class="hide_on_desktop">
      <img src="{{ block.settings.image_hero_mobile | img_url: 'large' }}" />
    </a>
    {% else %}
    <a href="{{ block.settings.hero_link }}" class="hide_on_desktop">
      <img src="{{ block.settings.image_hero | img_url: 'large' }}" />
    </a>
    {% endif %}

    {% if block.settings.image_hero != blank %}
      <a href="{{ block.settings.hero_link }}" class="hide_on_mobile">
        <img src="{{ block.settings.image_hero | img_url: 'master' }}" />
      </a>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
  <div class="hero_text hide_on_desktop">
    {% if block.settings.hero_subtitle_mobile == true %}
    <h3>{{ block.settings.hero_subtitle }}</h3>
    {% endif %}
    {% if block.settings.hero_title_mobile == true %}
    <h2>{{ block.settings.hero_title }}</h2>
    {% endif %}
    {% if block.settings.hero_text_mobile == true %}
    <p>{{ block.settings.hero_text }}</p>
    {% endif %}
    <a href="{{ block.settings.hero_link }}">
      <button class="button">{{ block.settings.hero_button_text }}</button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<hr class="hide_on_desktop" />

{% when 'featured_collection' %}
<div class="featured_collection">
  <h2>{{ block.settings.featured_collection_title }}</h2>
  {% for product in collections[block.settings.featured_collection_collection].products %}
  {% include 'bold-product' with product, hide_action: 'skip' %}
  
  <div class="product">
    <a href="{{ product.url }}">
      <div class="product_list_image" style="background-image:url({{ product.images[2] | product_img_url: 'large' }});">
        <img src="{{ product.featured_image | img_url: 'large' }}">
      </div>
      <div class="product_title"><h3>{{ product.title }}</h3></div>
      <p class="collection_product_price {% if product.compare_at_price > product.price %}on_sale{% endif %}">
        <span class="original_price">{{ product.compare_at_price | money }}</span>
        <span class="{% if product.compare_at_price > product.price %}sale_{% endif %}price">{{ product.price | money }}</span>
      </p>
    </a>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div><!-- end .featured_collection -->
<hr class="hide_on_desktop" />

{% endcase %}
{% endfor %}

<style type="text/css">
/* Full Image Hero */
.full_image_hero_container img{display:block; height:auto; width:100%;}
/* Hero Image and Text */
.hero_image_and_text_container{padding:9% 7% 0;}
.hero_image_and_text_container.full_width{padding:0;}
.hero_image_and_text_container h2{font-size:43px; font-weight:300; text-transform:uppercase;}
.hero_image_and_text_container h3{font-size:12px; font-weight:300; margin-top:3em; text-transform:uppercase;}
.hero_image_and_text_container p{font-size:28px;}
.hero_image img{height:auto; width:100%;}
.hero_text{text-align:center;}
.hero_image_and_text_container.full_width .hero_text p{padding:0 2% 2%;}
hr{border:none; border-top:1px solid #DCDDDE; margin:9% auto; width:75%;}
    /* Desktop */
    @media screen and (min-width:1098px){
      .hero_image_and_text_container,.hero_image_and_text_container.full_width{
          align-items:center;
          display:flex;
          padding:5%;
      }
      .hero_image_and_text_container > div{display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; width:47%;}
      .hero_text.float_left{padding-right:5%;}
      .hero_text.float_right{order:2; padding-left:5%;}
      .hero_text.hide_on_desktop{display:none;}
    }
    /* Mobile Only */
    @media screen and (max-width:1097px){
      .hero_image_and_text_container{background-color:white !important;}
    }
/* Featured Collection */
.featured_collection{padding:0 4%; text-align:center;}
.featured_collection h2{font-size:25px; font-weight:300; margin-bottom:1.5em; text-transform:uppercase;}
.featured_collection .product{display:inline-block; margin-bottom:3em; vertical-align:top; width:44%;}
.featured_collection .product:nth-of-type(even){margin-left:2%;}
.featured_collection .product img{display:block; height:auto; width:100%;}
.featured_collection a{text-decoration:none;}
.product_title h3{font-size:12px; font-weight:300; margin-bottom:.5em;}
.collection_product_price{font-size:11px; margin-top:0;}
.collection_product_price .price{font-weight:700; letter-spacing:2;}
  /* Desktop */
    @media screen and (min-width:1098px){
      .featured_collection h2{display:none;}
      .featured_collection .product{width:18%;}
      .featured_collection .product:nth-of-type(even){margin-left:3%;}
      .featured_collection .product{margin:0 3% 3em;}
    }
</style>


{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Home Page Slider",
    "blocks": [
        {
          "type"        :   "full_image_hero",
          "name"        :   "Full Image Hero",
          "settings"    : [
            {
              "type"    :   "image_picker",
              "id"      :   "image_hero",
              "label"   :   "Hero Image",
              "info"    :   "1,366 x 548"
            }, 
            {
              "type"    :   "image_picker",
              "id"      :   "image_hero_mobile",
              "label"   :   "Hero Image Mobile"
            }, 
            {
              "id"      :   "hero_link",
              "type"    :   "url",
              "label"   :   "Hero link"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type"        :   "hero_image_and_text",
          "name"        :   "Hero Image and Text",
          "settings"    : [
            {
              "type"    :   "image_picker",
              "id"      :   "image_hero",
              "label"   :   "Hero Image",
              "info"    :   "820 x 820"
            },
            {
              "type"    :   "image_picker",
              "id"      :   "image_hero_mobile",
              "label"   :   "Hero Image Mobile"
            },
            {
               "id"     :   "mobile_image_full_width",
               "type"   :   "checkbox",
               "default":   true,
               "label"  :   "Make image on mobile full width"
            },
            {
              "id"      :   "hero_link",
              "type"    :   "url",
              "label"   :   "Hero link"
            },
            {
               "id"     :   "hero_subtitle",
               "type"   :   "text",
               "label"  :   "Hero subtitle"
            },
            {
               "id"     :   "hero_subtitle_mobile",
               "type"   :   "checkbox",
               "default":   true,
               "label"  :   "Show hero subtitle on mobile"
            },
            {
               "id"     :   "hero_title",
               "type"   :   "text",
               "label"  :   "Hero title"
            },
            {
               "id"     :   "hero_title_mobile",
               "type"   :   "checkbox",
               "default":   true,
               "label"  :   "Show hero title on mobile"
            },
            {
               "id"     :   "hero_text",
               "type"   :   "textarea",
               "label"  :   "Hero Text"
            },
            {
               "id"     :   "hero_text_mobile",
               "type"   :   "checkbox",
               "default":   true,
               "label"  :   "Show hero text on mobile"
            },
            {
               "id"     :   "hero_button_text",
               "type"   :   "text",
               "default":   "Shop Now",
               "label"  :   "Hero button text"
            },
            {
               "id"     :   "hero_background_color",
               "type"   :   "color",
               "label"  :   "Hero background color",
               "default":   "#F7F7F7"
            },
            {
               "id"     :   "hero_layout_format",
               "type"   :   "select",
               "options": [
                  { "value": "left",    "label": "Text Left - Image Right"},
                  { "value": "right",   "label": "Text Right - Image Left"}
               ],
               "label"  :   "Hero layout format"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "featured_collection",
          "name": "Home Page Slider",
          "settings": [
            {
               "type": "text",
               "id": "featured_collection_title",
               "label": "Featured Collection Title"
            },
            {
               "type": "collection",
               "id": "featured_collection_collection",
               "label": "Featured Collection"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
{% endschema %}

{% stylesheet %}
{% endstylesheet %}

{% javascript %}
{% endjavascript %}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where is this style tag ? Inside blocks loop ? Kindly share complete code for the section.

Comment: @BilalAkbar File added.

Comment: I don't see  any liquid variable inside style tag in your added  file. What I meant to say earlier is that, if you want to use some block setting, then the style tag should also be inside the for loop that iterates over blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to specify the color of the active point at the **Blocks level**, but rather at the **section level**, as it is a global setting for the whole section and does not change from one block to another, proceed as follows :

- place this piece of code at the start of your section file:

```
<style>
  /* Color of active silder dot */
    .slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
      color: {{section.settings.colorDotActive }};
    }
</style>
```

- Then add the global settings to the entire section at the very beginning of the Schema tag, even before opening the settings specific to the Blocks, as follows:

```
{% schema %}
{
    "name": "Home Page Slider",
     "settings": [
          {
                    "type": "text",
                    "id": "sliderSpeed",
                    "label": "Slider Speed",
                    "default": "300",
                    "info": "1000 = 1 second"
                 },
                 {
                  "type": "color",
                  "id": "colorDotActive",
                  "label": "Active Dot Color",
                  "default": "#ff0000"
                },
                {
                  "type": "color",
                  "id": "colorDot",
                  "label": "Dot Color",
                  "default": "#0000ff"
                }
        ],
        "blocks": [
            .... Your old block setting.....
            
          ]
        }
{% endschema %}
```